# view.getId is -1 in onClick Listener

Tags: java, android

I'm inflating a view, setting it's ID, set some tags, set an onClickListener on it and add it to a parent view.

```
LinearLayout llCategoryListIncome = (LinearLayout)calculatorFlipContainerBack.findViewById(R.id.ll_category_list_income);
// inflate category item
LinearLayout categoryItem = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_category_item,
                        container,
                        false);

Integer id = 2;
Integer position = 3;

categoryItem.setId(position);
categoryItem.setTag(R.string.tag_category_position, position);
categoryItem.setTag(R.string.tag_category_id, id);
categoryItem.setOnClickListener(this);
llCategoryListIncome.addView(categoryItem);
```

In the onClick Listener I want to check this ID. But the ID is always -1. Same issue with the tags. The tags are always null.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   Integer position = (Integer)view.getTag(R.string.tag_category_position);
   Integer id = (Integer)view.getTag(R.string.tag_category_id);

   Log.d(TAG, "view get id " + view.getId());   // is null
   Log.d(TAG, "position is " + position);   // is null
   Log.d(TAG, "id is " + id);   // is -1
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your clicked view is really your linear layout and not another widget inside?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I removed the setOnClickListener call and checked whether the onClick is called - and it is not called.

Comment: Is that a typo? Where does `view` come from?

Comment: Oh my god.. yes that was the typo and the reason it did not work. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You must use id and not string resource when you assign a Tag.

Use something like

```
categoryItem.setTag(R.id.your_id_for_position, position);
```

instead of

```
categoryItem.setTag(R.string.tag_category_position, position);
```

As said in the [View class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object))

> The specified key should be an id declared in the resources of the application to ensure it is unique

Comment: As I mentioned above the typo was the issue. Reading the docs, I think your answer is also correct. But strangely enough - it works also with R.string. tag_category_position  ..

Answer (score 0):

Why you call setTag twice ?

you have to setTag once by below line:

```
categoryItem.setTag(position);
```

Onclick method

```
Integer id = (Integer)view.getTag();
Log.d(TAG, "id is " + id);
```

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define and use a holder inside your code.

```
private class TagHolder
{
    int id; int position;
}
TagHolder tagHolder = new TagHolder();
tagHolder.id = 2;
tagHolder.position = 3;
view.setTag(tagHolder);

public void onClick(View v) {
    TagHolder tagHolder = (TagHolder)view.getTag();
    // tagHolder.id, tagHolder.position
}
```